# Totally ramified principal ideal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

Let $K$ be a number field of degree $d=[K,\mathbb{Q}]$ and suppose that the class number $h_K$ of $K$ is comprime with $d$. Let $p$ a prime of $\mathbb{Q}$ and assume that $(p)=\mathcal{P}^d$ is totally ramified in $K$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the unique prime of $K$ above $p$. Show that $[\mathcal{P}]=1$ in the class group $Cl_K$ of $K$.

Since $\mathcal{P}^d$ is totally ramified, then $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathcal{P}^d \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and so It is a maximal ideal.

I think that I have to prove that $\mathcal{P}=p\mathcal{O}_K$ but I have no idea how to use $(p,h_K)=1$.

some ideas?

Comment: Hint: what is the order of $[\mathcal{P}]$, seen as an element of the class group?

Comment: @Aphelli : The order of $[\mathcal{P}]$ is a divisor of $d$ and it has to divide $h_K$, and then?

Comment: Which hypothesis haven’t you used yet?

Comment: Actually I didn’t use anything. 
The hypothesis $(h_K,p)=1$ makes me think about Bezout but I have to combine this with the order of $\mathcal{P}$. 
And I used the hypothesis “totally ramified” just to say that $\mathcal{P}^d$ is maximal, but in no  other ways.

Comment: Please read your previous comment aloud (that is, your reply to my first comment), then the first sentence of your post (still aloud). Do it again a couple of times… you don’t need anything more.

Comment: I’m sure that now I have to do only a little conclusion but I’m a bit confused. Since $\mathcal{P}^d$ is maximal and holds that $… \subseteq \mathcal{P}^n \subseteq \mathcal{P}^{n-1} \subseteq … \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ then $\mathcal{P}^d=\mathcal{P}=(p)$ and so $\mathcal{P}$ is principal. But I’m not sure of this argument. It seems too easy and I don’t see when and where I’m using that $(p, h_K)=1$. Probably I’m getting lost in a glass of water…

Comment: I have no idea why you decide that $\mathcal{P}^d=\mathcal{P}$. This is certainly false (eg $p=5$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$?)… but the order of $\mathcal{P}$ in the class group is a divisor of $d$ and $h_K$. Since these numbers are coprime, said order must be $1$, which means that $\mathcal{P}$ is principal.

Comment: I’was trying to use that $(p,h_K)=1$, but my hypothesis is that $(d,h_K)=1$. Thank you very much